# How to apply the same string constants to a multiple float values using python?

Tags: python

I have a series of values in one file and I want to add two "descriptors" to all the series of values using python script.

Example:

Values:

```
1 2 3  
1 3 4
```

Descriptors:

```
Ford truck
```

End result:

```
1 2 3 Ford truck  
1 3 4 Ford truck
```

I would appreciate any help. I have looked at hstack, but am unsure this is the best approach.

Comment: Do you want to write the descriptors in the file itself?

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Please show your code so we can help you fix it.

Comment: Cuber: yes, I want to writer the descriptors to the file itself. Also, the descriptors would be in a separate file. In the example, Descriptor 1 = Ford and Descriptor 2 = truck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the name of the raw file is `fname` and the name of the output file should be `outputFile` you could do this:

```
with open(fname) as inputFile:
    content = inputFile.readlines()
    content = [x.strip() + "Ford truck" for x in content]

    with open(ofname, "w") as outputFile:
        for item in content:
            outputFile.write("%s\n" % item)
```

This code will read all lines of your raw input file, removes all trailing white space, adds `Ford truck` to each line and saves the result on the output file.